# jira res-api create issue with bullets list in description

Tags: jira-rest-api

Hi i want to create a jira issue with bullet list and other formating from rest-api 
Right know i am testing this code, but it returns

```
{
"errorMessages": [],
"errors": {
    "description": "Operation value must be a string"
 }
}
```

Body looks like this

```
{
"fields": {
    "project": {
        "key": "DWH"
    },
    "issuetype": {
        "name": "Story"
    },
    "summary": "auto created datatask",

    "description":  "description":  ["Pro:<fil pro and activity number provided>.",
                    "Tablename:<fill table name>.",
                    "Table view:<fill table view name>.",
                    "endpoint:<fill knudepunkt>.",
                    "Task to do.",
                    "*Copy attached document to metadata/new folder.",
                    "* Run job to create the table.", 
                    "* Test the data in Production when ready.",
                    "* Create extra userstory"],

    "assignee": {
        "key": "bdmdwhdata",
        "name": "bdmdwhdata",
        "emailAddress": "dwhdata@bankdata.dk"
    },
    "labels": ["DATA"]


 }      
}
```

Is it possible to create multiline decription from REST-API in jira issues

I i jost write a single line in description it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For adding new lines, try using `\n` in the description. For more information, kindly check this [documentation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirakb/how-to-insert-a-new-line-when-using-lines-the-jira-core-rest-api-779160736.html).